# Server response: .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [java.lang.NullPointerException]

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, servlets, nullpointerexception

I am building a user login page. The server returns the following null pointer exception (below) when I input the right user mobile and password. "Other Exception" is printed from GlobalExceptionHandler

.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [java.lang.NullPointerException]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx5V6.png)

Also, the public RespBean doLogin(@Valid LoginVo loginVo, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) function under LoginController doesn't run. (System.out.println("LoginController doLogin running"); doesn't get printed out). The null pointer exception happens before the mobile and the password are received from the server.

Before adding HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response as inputs into the function, the user login worked fine and the doLogin function gets executed in full. After adding these two input, the null pointer exception happens.

Could I please get some guidance on how I can identify what cause the null pointer exception?

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>


    <!-- jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <!-- jquery-validator -->
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/jquery-validation/localization/messages_zh.min.js}"></script>
    <!-- layer -->
        <!-- pop ups-->
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/layer/layer.js}"></script>
    <!-- md5.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/md5.min.js}"></script>
    <!-- common.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/common.js}"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        html,body{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
        body{
            background:url('@{/img/bg.jpg}') no-repeat;
            background-size:100% 100%;
            padding-top:100px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" method="post"  style="width:50%; margin:0 auto;">

    <h2 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 20px">User Login</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="form-label col-md-4">Please input your mobile number</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <!-- mobile len requirement 11 digits-->
                <input id="mobile" name = "mobile" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="mobile-number" required="true"  minlength="11" maxlength="11" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="form-label col-md-4">Please input your password</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <!-- password len requirement 6-16 digits-->
                <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password"  placeholder="password" required="true" minlength="6" maxlength="16" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:40px;">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="reset" onclick="reset()">reset</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="login()">login</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
<script>


    function login(){
        // validate content in the table first, after validation passes, call doLogin function
        $("#loginForm").validate({
            submitHandler:function(form){
                doLogin();
            }
        });
    }
    function doLogin(){
        g_showLoading();

        //get password input from user and do the first MD5 encoding
        var inputPass = $("#password").val();
        var salt = g_passsword_salt;
        var str = "" + salt.charAt(0) + salt.charAt(2) + inputPass + salt.charAt(5) + salt.charAt(4);
        var password = md5(str);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/login/doLogin",
            type: "POST",
            data:{
                mobile:$("#mobile").val(),
                password: password
            },
            success:function(data){

                layer.closeAll();
                if(data.code == 200){
                    layer.msg("login successful");
    
                    window.location.href="/goods/toList";
                }else{
                    layer.msg("something wrong")
                    layer.msg(data.message); // data.msg won't work
                }
            },
            error:function(){
                layer.closeAll();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.xxxx.seckill.controller;

import com.xxxx.seckill.service.IUserService;
import com.xxxx.seckill.vo.LoginVo;
import com.xxxx.seckill.vo.RespBean;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
//should not use RestController, should use Controller; RestController will add response body to all methods under this class, will return a body, not jumping to another page
@RequestMapping("/login")
@Slf4j //lombok, for logging output e.g. log infor, log warning, log error
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/toLogin") //to log in page 跳转登录页
    public String toLogin(){
        return "login";
    }

    
    @RequestMapping("/doLogin")
    @ResponseBody
    //公用返回对象 response bean, to return response bean, need to @ResponseBody
    public RespBean doLogin(@Valid LoginVo loginVo, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("LoginController doLogin running");
        // 接受传参 receive parameter from users with LoginVo
        log.info("{}", loginVo); //log can be used directly as it is included in Slf4j
        return userService.doLogin(loginVo, request, response);
//        return null;
    }
}
```

UserService
The doLogin function doesn't get executed. None of the System.out.println gets printed.

```
public interface IUserService extends IService<User> {


    RespBean doLogin(LoginVo loginVo, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response);

}
```

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl<UserMapper, User> implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public RespBean doLogin(LoginVo loginVo, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("userService doLogin");
        String mobile = loginVo.getMobile();
        String password = loginVo.getPassword();


        // find user with mobile
        User user = userMapper.selectById(mobile);
        System.out.println("user is not null, user mapper injected");
        if (null == user) {
            System.out.println("user doesn't exist");
            throw new GlobalException(RespBeanEnum.LOGIN_ERROR);
        }

        // verify whether user password is correct
        if (!MD5Util.frontPassToDBPass(password, user.getSalt()).equals(user.getPassword())) {

            System.out.println("wrong password");
            throw new GlobalException(RespBeanEnum.LOGIN_ERROR);

        }
        System.out.println("generating cookie");
        //generate cookie
        String ticket = UUIDUtil.uuid();
        request.getSession().setAttribute(ticket, user);
        CookieUtil.setCookie(request, response, "userTicket", ticket);
        return RespBean.success();
    }
}
```

GlobalExceptionHandler

```
@RestControllerAdvice // will return a response body
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public RespBean ExceptionHangler(Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof GlobalException) {
            System.out.println("GlobalException");
            GlobalException ex = (GlobalException) e;
            return RespBean.error(ex.getRespBeanEnum());
        } else if (e instanceof BindException) {
            System.out.println("BindException");
            BindException ex = (BindException) e;
            RespBean respBean = RespBean.error(RespBeanEnum.BIND_ERROR);
            respBean.setMessage("Validation error: " + ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage());
            return respBean;
        }
        System.out.println("Other Exception");
        return RespBean.error(RespBeanEnum.ERROR);

    }
}
```

I tried rebuilding the project in IDEA. And I added all these system.out.println to identify the cause. None of the system.out.println got printed except the "Other Exception" from GlobalExceptionHandler.

Comment: I figured it out. The null pointer exception comes from loginVo = null in public RespBean doLogin(@Valid LoginVo loginVo, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response). Without "@Valid" the program runs fine. So the problem happens during validation / exception handling process. I realise there is a type in ExceptionHangler(Exception e). Should be "ExceptionHandler". Annotations like ExceptionHandler and ControllerAdvice use reflection to discover and apply the functionality defined in your classes. These annotations rely on correctly named methods to handle specific exceptions.

Comment: Can you please write your solution as an answer to the question and accept it? comments are not meant for answers and they're not very noticeable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The null pointer exception comes from loginVo = null in public RespBean doLogin(@Valid LoginVo loginVo, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response). Without "@Valid" the program runs fine. So the problem happens during validation / exception handling process. I realise there is a type in ExceptionHangler(Exception e). Should be "ExceptionHandler". Annotations like ExceptionHandler and ControllerAdvice use reflection to discover and apply the functionality defined in your classes. These annotations rely on correctly named methods to handle specific exceptions.